# How to make AES inversed mix_column in python

Tags: python, cryptography, aes, xor

I'm currently using this code to make a small example of AES

```
mix_columns_matrix = [
    [0x2, 0x3, 0x1, 0x1],
    [0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x1],
    [0x1, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3],
    [0x3, 0x1, 0x1, 0x2]
]

def mix_columns(state):
    new_state = [[0 for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            result = 0
            for k in range(4):
                result ^= state[k][j] * mix_columns_matrix[i][k]
            new_state[i][j] = result & 0xF  # Limit to 4 bits
    return new_state`
```

And when i use it I have :

```
Before MixColumns:
   
['0x3', '0x6', '0x5', '0xc']
['0xd', '0xe', '0x8', '0xa']
['0x1', '0xf', '0x4', '0x7']
['0x0', '0x2', '0xb', '0x9']

After MixColumns:
['0x0', '0xb', '0xd', '0x8']
['0xa', '0x5', '0x2', '0x4']
['0xc', '0x0', '0x4', '0x3']
['0x5', '0x7', '0x5', '0xb']
```

So I've try to create the reverse function

```
def inv_mix_columns(state):
    inv_mix_columns_matrix = [
        [0xE, 0xB, 0xD, 0x9],
        [0x9, 0xE, 0xB, 0xD],
        [0xD, 0x9, 0xE, 0xB],
        [0xB, 0xD, 0x9, 0xE]
    ]

    new_state = [[0 for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            result = 0
            for k in range(4):
                result ^= state[k][j] * inv_mix_columns_matrix[i][k]
            new_state[i][j] = result & 0xF  # Limit to 4 bits
    return new_state
```

And with the previous result i get :

```
['0x3', '0x7', '0x7', '0xb']
['0x5', '0x3', '0xa', '0xd']
['0x1', '0x6', '0x6', '0x4']
['0xc', '0xb', '0x5', '0xe']
```

I don't understand why I don't have the first input as a result and how to fix it.

I've tried several forms of `inv_mix_columns` and check several times my matrices, but I still can't figure out what's happing..
I'm wondering if I'm well used the XOR function

Of course, I don't want to use library since it's an example

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
def mix_columns(state_matrix, mix_matrix):
    state_matrix = np.array(state_matrix)
    mix_matrix = np.array(mix_matrix)
    mixed_state = np.zeros_like(state_matrix, dtype=int)
    
    for col in range(4):
        for row in range(4):
            mixed_state[row][col] = gf_add_mul(state_matrix[:, col], mix_matrix[row, :])
    
    return mixed_state

def inv_mix_columns(state_matrix, inv_mix_matrix):
    state_matrix = np.array(state_matrix)
    inv_mix_matrix = np.array(inv_mix_matrix)
    mixed_state = np.zeros_like(state_matrix, dtype=int)
    
    for col in range(4):
        for row in range(4):
            mixed_state[row][col] = gf_add_mul(state_matrix[:, col], inv_mix_matrix[row, :])
    
    return mixed_state

def gf_add_mul(a, b):
    p = 0
    for i in range(4):
        p ^= gf_mul(a[i], b[i])
    return p

def gf_mul(a, b):
    p = 0
    for _ in range(4):
        if b & 1:
            p ^= a
        hi_bit_set = a & 0x8
        a <<= 1
        if hi_bit_set:
            a ^= 0x3
        b >>= 1
    return p & 0xF
```

I've got the solution it's because multiplication and modulo operations must be done using finite field rules GF(2^4) on bytes. This means that addition and multiplication must be performed in this particular context. And I used numpy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).